# How to use instagram secure API requests with ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, instagram, instagram-api

My steps are:

1. update gem `gem update instagram` to instagram-1.1.6
2. add `config.client_ips = "100.100.1.0"` to the code (hide real ip)
3. check checkbox `Enforce signed requests` in developer page, click save

But I still get following error:

```
#<Hashie::Mash code=403 error_message="Invalid signed-request: Missing required parameter 'sig'" error_type="OAuthForbiddenException">
```

When I try to get posts or create like.

What's going wrong? What additional action needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You use older types of signatures

On September 1, instagram only accepts new type https://instagram.com/developer/secure-api-requests/

Comment: I see, that's why I Update instagram gem, where all necessary movements for creating sign request already done

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make signed calls with instagram ruby gem, I updated the gem, and In client configuration is as follows `Instagram.client({:client_id => ENV["INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID"],:access_token => actkn, :client_secret => ENV["INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET"], :sign_requests => true})`, but it still shows above said error `403 - sig missing`  is i'm missing something